# Why isset() always returns FALSE on custom Object

Tags: php

I cannot understand this behavior: My `isset()` check is always returning **false** on a `property` that has a value for sure!

```
<?php

  class User {
    protected $userId; // always filled
    protected $userName; // always filled

    /**
     * Magic method for the getters.
     * 
     * @param type $property
     * @return \self|property
     */
    public function __get($property) {
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
            return $this->$property;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('property '.$property.' does not exist in '.__CLASS__.' class');
        }
    }

  }

?>
```

When I check this variable from another class with the following:

```
isset($loggedUser->userName); // loggedUser is my instantiation of the User.php
```

It returns `FALSE`?? But when I overload the `__isset()` function in my User.php I get `TRUE` back as I expected:

```
public function __isset($name)
{
    return isset($this->$name);
}
```

Just to be clear:

```
echo $loggedUser->name;   // result "Adis"
isset($loggedUser->name); // results in FALSE, but why?
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$userName` is protected, which means you can't access it outside the class, in this example from your `$loggedUser` init. 
You need one of the following:
1) make it `public`
2) write a custom method
3) make a magic(__isset) function

EDIT: When using isset() on inaccessible object properties, the __isset() overloading method will be called, if declared.[isset() php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

I hope this explains it.

Comment: Hi, See updated question, I have the magic method defined, that is why  I do not understand the behavior...

Comment: @adis `return $this->$property;` should be `return $this->property;` without the dollar sign

Comment: @adis you access methods and properties of objects without the dollar sign like: `$this->property` or `$this->method()`. if you use the dollar sign it will use the string of the variable as the method/property name, like so : `$string = "propertyName"; $this->$string;` this is the same as doing `$this->propertyName`

Comment: This does not work! Do you have working code sample with class properties where the __get is defined as you describe, without the `$`-sign?

Comment: @adis oh sorry, in your case with the __get method its should be fine, I got confused... what's the actual output you are getting? can you echo the response from `$loggedUser->userName`? does it throw an exception or does it return null?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18107/discussion-between-flame-and-adis)

Answer (score 6):

`protected` attributes are only visible from within the object's methods. They are hidden from view from outside access.

---

```
class prot_text {
    protected $cannot_see_me;
    function see_me() {
       echo $this->cannot_see_me;
    }
}

$x = new prot_text();
echo $x->cannot_see_me; // does not work - accessing from "outside"
$x->see_me(); // works, accessing the attribute from "inside".
```

Comment: Is this even the case when I have the magic method `__get($property)` defined in this class? Because my echo actually works.. I'm confused now.. I updated my question with my `__get` method.

Answer (score 1):

$userName is protected, so it's only accessible from inside the class it's defined in, or any classes that extend it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the property is protected. A protected property cannot be accessed outside of the object (or child objects). The overloaded function is defined within the class, so that works fine.

This a feature of OOP: (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)
If you want to make it accessible everywhere, define the property as public, otherwise wrap that particular function in a public function.