# weird issue with isset

Tags: php, isset

```
var_dump($obj->key);
var_dump(isset($obj->key));
```

In the above code, the first line returns a huge object dump but the second line returns false. How is it possible? Is there any scenarios where the object might exist but still isset returns false ?

Answer:-

```
<?php
  class SomeKlass {
    public function __get($name) {
      return $name;
    }
  }

  $a = new SomeKlass;
  var_dump($a->bar);
  var_dump(isset($a->bar));
?>
```

The first line prints the value but the second line prints false

usage of magic function `__get()` causes this

Comment: What is the output of the vardump's ?

Comment: If `$obj->key` is accessed via a magic `__get()` method, but no magic `__isset()` method is defined

Comment: What is $obj? can you post some code and the output?

Comment: [Demo](http://ideone.com/p89qr7) showing how to reproduce this situation

Comment: @MarkBaker I think thats the issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isset() always returns FALSE on custom Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899547/why-isset-always-returns-false-on-custom-object)